# Retrieve EXE file version from file in current directory

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script that is in version control and can be checked out into any directory, but it should only work on the current directory:

```
@echo off
zip -9 Setup.zip Setup.exe SetupGuide.pdf
```

Now the batch file should retrieve from Setup.exe the version, check a network drive whether the file Setup.<versionstring>.zip exists and throw an error if it does, or else copy the Setup.zip to the network drive as Setup.<versionstring>.zip.

I found that I can get the version string using WMIC, but it seems to only take the full path name and furthermore needs double backslashes. How can I tell WMIC that I want a file from the current directory?

```
T:\Installer\SetupFiles>wmic datafile where name='.\\Setup.exe' get version
Keine Instanzen verfügbar.
```

Comment: `(Get-Item $filename).VersionInfo.FileVersion` would work, but that's PowerShell.  Are you married to using only a batch file?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to provide the full path to the executable:

```
wmic datafile where name="T:\\Installer\\SetupFiles\\Setup.exe" get version
```